# Generalized inverse matrix rules

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, generalized-inverse

I would like to ask how free you are when you are calculating generalized inverses? I know, that it is said that there are infinite many of them, but we always usually choose submatrix such that elements are picked in square shape so it is easy to put them back in original matrix.

For example would it really be possible to get next matrix and if not why not and if yes how?:
$\begin{bmatrix}1 &0 &0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what version of "generalized inverse" you're talking about.  The [Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of the given matrix is

$$ \left[\matrix{1 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\cr}\right]$$

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but I want to find example of matrix that provides generalized inverse that I mentioned in question. I don't want inverse of given matrix

Comment: ... and the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of my matrix is your matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Given a rank-deficient matrix $A$, here is a method to calculate a generalized inverse $A^-$ such that
$$AA^-A = A$$
Eliminating columns/rows $\big($i.e. cols $\#2,4$ and row $\#4\big)$ yields a full-rank *reduced* matrix
$$A_r=\begin{bmatrix}1 &0 &0 \\0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
Calculate $A_r^{-1}\,$ then re-insert zero rows/cols $\big($rows $\#2,4$ and col $\#4\big)$ to obtain
$$A^- = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
This process does not necessarily generate the Moore-Penrose inverse $A^+$ (however for this particular matrix it does). See page 9 of these
[course notes](https://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/guangliang.chen/Math253S20/lec6ginverse.pdf) for some examples.